# Possible migration from sound.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked a question on [sound.SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/46971/25426) regarding the DC/AC output of an SPL meter.

I was hesitant regarding the best suited SE website. Since the question is pretty specific to audio, I choose *sound.SE*. But I didn't get much feedback there.

Do you think it would be better suited to *electronics.SE*?

FWIW, I made the same requests on [dsp.meta.SE](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1673/46389).

Answer (score 2):

The question, as it stands, would only be marginally suitable for EE.SE, because it requires us to speculate about the internal implementations of commercial products. The best source for that kind of information would be the manufacturers themselves.

However, if you want to instead ask the more general question of the best way to measure RT<sub>60</sub> using a computer, then DSP.SE is probably your best bet. You plug a microphone into your sound card and do the processing entirely in software — no EE required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dave. I initially thought the SPL meters' analog output was somehow standardized. But as you said, it seems to be manufacturer-dependent. The more I think about the problem, the more I think I will use  a software-only solution :/